# "notebook==6.0.2 cannot be installed on this environment" on python 3.5 environment

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, python-3.5

I have created a new env on anaconda, specifically python 3.5 so that it is compatible with some of the packages I use.
But installing jupyter notebook or spyder seems impossible. I get this error message on the title.
I have tried

```
conda install -c anaconda jupyter
```

but it is taking forever and I don't think it is going to install.

Answer (score 0):

Conda packages for Python 3.5 stopped being created shortly after Python 3.6 was released. So most new versions of things like Spyder and the Jupyter notebook are not available for it.